# Service fabric - architecture decision - Pictures

Tags: azure, model-view-controller, azure-service-fabric

I can't make decision if is service fabric good candidate for pictures storage in  multitenant app. Each tenant can have approx. 1GB of images. Can be service fabric replacement for blobs or COSMOS DB? 
I thing, its not good, but Im not sure... (no document about this found...-but Microsoft run some type of data services on service fabric...)

I would like use service fabric stateless service for images upload to some kind of DB service... Maybe with using some queue for it in statefull service...

Your opinions are welcome...

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

From a pure cost perspective your cheapest option (and my recommendation) would be to go with Azure Blob Storage. It's going to be orders of magnitude cheaper compared to writing the images into the hard drives on your SF cluster or even compared to storing them as attachments in CosmosDB. Your SF stateless service could receive the Image and upload the bytes to Blob storage and then store the URI somewhere to be retrieved later.

Comment: Jess comment is correct. There is one more thing I think it might be useful is after uploading the images it is likely you have to do post-upload processing of the image i.e. generate thumbnail or generate meta data about the image. Having a queue and stateless service in Service Fabric is really useful where can scale them up with high upload traffic